# Check if last character is a question mark

Tags: php

How do I check if the last character in a string is a question mark (?) using php?

This is my current attempt but it doesn't seem to work unfortunately:

```
if (substr(strrev(trim($link)),0,0) != "?")
{

}
```

Comment: For what its worth, I've added an answer that explains *why what you wrote wasn't doing what you expected*, and explains how you can achieve the result in an easier way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if (substr(rtrim($link), -1) != "?") { 
  // Do stuff
}
```

Giving a negative `start` value to `substr()` makes it count from the end instead of the beginning.

Comment: I wonder if anyone can come up with a better solution but I'm not holding my breath... This is pretty optimal, I think. Would `!==` be better?

Comment: I resisted using `preg_match()` :)

Comment: @Floris: Don't forget about double quotes

Comment: This looks like the best one to me!

Comment: I don't think `!==` is necessary in this case. This isn't a case where automatic conversion could change the result.

Comment: True - but would it be (very marginally) more efficient since both sides of the comparison are strings? Or am I missing something subtle?

Comment: If you want to benchmark it, go ahead. I don't worry about negligible performance differences like that. Have you ever heard of premature optimization?

Answer (score 1):

There are two main errors with your code. Firstly, the comparision is wrong. You are asking if the last character *is not* a question mark. Also, you are getting a 0 length substring, so that will always be not equal to a question mark, since `'' != '?'` is always `True`.

With your original code you can change it to this:

```
if (substr(strrev(trim($link)),0,1) == "?")
{
    //Do things
}
```

Alternatively, this is slightly shorter and just counts the index for the substring from the end:

```
$link = "Say what?";
if (substr($link,-1) == "?")
{
 echo "You heard me!";
}
```

Comment: The default length for `substr` is until the end of the string, not 1.

Comment: @Barmar Eeek, my bad. All fixed.

Answer (score 0):

it's php, there are always alternatives:

```
$link='123?';
if (end(str_split($link)) == "?"){
    echo 'YES';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is:

```
if (substr("question?", -1) == '?')
```

Sometimes I check also other marks like `?` `!` or `.` :

```
if (in_array(substr("question?", -1), ['?', '!' , '.']))
```